# removing Bookmarks from Ubuntu's 14.04

Tags: 14.04

In the File system on my Ubuntu 14.04 I have not only a `Places`, `Devices`, and `Network` labels, but also a `Bookmarks` with the couple of folders inside. Please share your thoughts on what `Bookmarks` represents and how to remove it (and its folders). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bookmarks` is a shortcut section for your favorite folders.

---

To bookmark a folder, click **Bookmarks** > **Bookmark this location**, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

To delete a bookmark, right click on the folder you want to remove and select **Remove**.

---

To remove the complete `Bookmarks` section, just delete every folder being present inside.

Comment: Hi hg8, thanks for the explanation and instructions !